# Formalization of adaptive sampling

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, applications

The notion on adaptive sampling or adaptive plotting is fairly popular, but I have not found a formal definition.

I have developed an algorithm for plotting implicit algebraic curves in the plane. The algorithm is adaptive in the sense that the sampled points are denser where the curvature is higher.

I would like to prove that my algorithm is adaptive, but I don´t know of a formal adaptive-sampling definition. Is there such a thing?